# Python calcualte new column based on condition of existing columns

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

Wanted a new column based on certain conditions of existing columns, below is what I am doing right now, but it takes too much time for huge data. Is there any efficient or faster way to do it.

```
DF["A"][0] = 0
for x in range(1,rows):
    if(DF["B"][x]>DF["B"][x-1]):
        DF["A"][x] = DF["A"][x-1] + DF["C"][x]
    elif(DF["B"][x]<DF["B"][x-1]):
        DF["A"][x] = DF["A"][x-1] - DF["C"][x]
    else:
        DF["A"][x] = DF["A"][x-1]
```

Comment: There is likely a simpler, more efficient boolean masking method to what you are trying to accomplish. We could better help solve your problem with a sample dataframe to work with, as well as what you expect your output to look like.

Answer (score 0):

> a new column based on certain conditions of existing columns,

I'm using the DataFrame provided by @zipa:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B': [12, 15, 9, 8, 15],
                   'C': [3, 9, 12, 6, 8]})
```

**First approach**

Here's a function that implements efficiently as you specified. It works by leveraging Pandas' indexing features, specifically row masks

```
def update(df):
    cond_larger = df['B'] > df['B'].shift().fillna(0)
    cond_smaller = df['B'] < df['B'].shift().fillna(0)
    cond_else = ~(cond_larger | cond_smaller)
    for cond, sign in [(cond_larger, +1),  # A[x-1] + C[x] 
                       (cond_smaller, -1), # A[x-1] - C[x]
                       (cond_else, 0)]:    # A[x-1] + 0
        if any(cond):
            df.loc[cond, 'A_updated'] = (df['A'].shift().fillna(0) + 
                                         sign * df[cond]['C'])
    df['A'] = df['A_updated']
    df.drop(columns=['A_updated'], inplace=True)
    return df

update(df)
=> 
      A   B   C
0   3.0  12   3
1  10.0  15   9
2 -10.0   9  12
3  -3.0   8   6
4  12.0  15   8
```

**Optimized**

It turns out you can use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask) to achieve the same as above. Note you could combine the conditions into the call of `mask`, however I find it easier to read like this:

```
# specify conditions
cond_larger = df['B'] > df['B'].shift().fillna(0)
cond_smaller = df['B'] < df['B'].shift().fillna(0)
cond_else = ~(cond_larger | cond_smaller)
# apply
A_shifted = (df['A'].shift().fillna(0)).copy()
df.mask(cond_larger, A_shifted + df['C'], axis=0, inplace=True)
df.mask(cond_smaller, A_shifted - df['C'], axis=0, inplace=True)
df.mask(cond_else, A_shifted, axis=0, inplace=True)
=>
(same results as above)
```

Notes:

- I'm assuming default value `0` for `A/B[x-1]`. If the first row should be treated differently remove or replace `.fillna(0)`. Results will be different.
- Conditions are checked in sequence. Depending on whether updates should use the original values in `A` or those updated in the previous condition you may not need the helper column `A_updated`
- See previous versions of this answer for a history of how I got here

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right this is what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B': [12, 15, 9, 8, 15],
                   'C': [3, 9, 12, 6, 8]})

df['A'] = np.where(df.index==0,
                   0,
                   np.where(df['B']>df['B'].shift(),
                            df['A']-df['A'].shift(),
                            np.where(df['B']<df['B'].shift(),
                                     df['A'].shift()-df['C'],
                                     df['A'].shift())))
df
#      A   B   C
#0   0.0  12   3
#1   1.0  15   9
#2 -10.0   9  12
#3  -3.0   8   6
#4   1.0  15   8
```

Comment: Good test dataframe & interesting approach using `np.where`. Please check my answer, not sure why but we get different results. From manual checking your solution seems to use intermediate results for `A[x-1]` during the update -- which may or may not be what the OP wants.